# AS3 - Change Text Before Run The Function

Tags: actionscript-3, function, text

I need make a loading screen. But Flash do not read codes line by line. How to change textbox text before run another function?

My code :

```
TextBox.text = "Processing...";
Process();
```

Example :

```
newMap.Mytxt.textColor = 0x00FF00;
newMap.Mytxt.text = "Processing...";
DefineMap(Number(newMap.newX.text),Number(newMap.newY.text));           
trace(map);
```

In my example : program create a map. but I want to show "Processing" text before creating map. This code is not working.

Comment: Can you show some more code please? This is not enough to answer your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, your problem is not about Flash running line by line. In fact, it does run line by line, but your problem is that you want to see the text change before running the function.
See the change text differs from changing the text. Your code actually changes the text, but the interface hasn't been changed yet through the eventDispatcher. If you're running on SDK 3.6A or newer, you can listen to afterChange event and call your function after the screen has been updated.

Edit: Your code "doesn't work" because since the execution of your function is so fast, it doesn't give the screen time to update to "Processing" before the map is already done, which makes it looks like the screen has been updated only once.

Edit 2: Here is a working code (note: You'll only see a glimpse of the "Waiting..." message because the process is too fast):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;

            // Function that starts everything
            private function changeValue():void{
                // Add Listener to the label to wait the screen to be updated BEFORE updating the text.
                this.status.addEventListener(Event.RENDER, this.changed);
                // Update the text
                this.status.text = "Wait...";
            }

            private function changed(e:Event):void{
                // Make sure to remove the eventListener to not cause infinite loop.
                this.status.removeEventListener(Event.RENDER, this.changed);
                // Make new change.
                this.status.text = "Done";
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>    
    <mx:Button x="221" y="185" label="Change it!" click="changeValue()"/>
    <mx:Text id="status" x="395" y="250" text="Text"/>

</mx:Application>
```

Comment: Can you give me an example ? how to trace a message before processing ?

Comment: I'm downloading Flash Player Debugger (long time since I don't work with AS3). Give me a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you doing in the Process() function? You should never but *never* block the main thread with processing intensive tasks because it will block your UI. Always delegate these calculations to a background worker or use some kind of enter frame event to do it in steps.

Comment: i don't wanna block main thread. i wanna show a message before main code.

Comment: That doesn't answer me question what you are doing in the Process() function. Is it CPU intensive? Why do you need to show the message in the first place? You could simply use a setTimeout(Process, 1000); if all you need to do is to postpone the function call to show the message...